# detecting addresses using NER and spaCy

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

How do I detect addresses using NER and spaCy.  NER detects names, organizations, dates, book titles, etc. While there are a lot of pre-trained models for names, there are none for addresses.

In the same way is it possible to detect addresses, street names, cities, zip codes, etc. Also, after detecting the address, is it possible to say whether it is Real or Fake?

Also, I find it difficult to get the datasets.  Kindly provide me with your suggestions or the best approach.

[Trying to get a similar visualization for the addresses also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbbN8.png)

Thank you

Comment: Same question on spaCy forums. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/11027